# How to cite USGS website refereing Landsat accuracy?

Tags: citations, citation-style, website, reference-managers

I want to cite the official Geometric accuracy of the Landsat imagery, published by USGS on their website http://landsat.usgs.gov/geometry.php. The citation is suggested for a scientific journal.

I am using Mendeley, which ask me to fill in:

- Title: Geometric Accuracy of Geometry???
- Authors: USGS??? or United States Geological Survey??
- Publication: Landsat Missions??
- Year: 2016 - I think this is obvious
- Pages: ??? What??? pages on website?

Date Accessed: - should I use the american or UK type of date? my paper is written in american english.

[image]

Comment: Doesn't Mendeley have a form for websites? They are a different category than books or papers in any reference style and in bibtex. Regarding date: I think you should use either ISO format (yyyy-mm-dd) or write the month in letters. Anything else is source of confusion.

Comment: Mendeley ask me to fill those information. I am not sure, if I indicate them right.

Comment: What are you writing for (thesis, journal, ect.)? That will dictate the answer to your formatting questions.

Comment: I am citing for a scientific journal

Comment: Each journal is different. I would follow follow the journal's directions. Some are okay with citing webpages as formal citations. Other require webpages to be cited as inline citations.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would try to cite the project documentation, which has its own [official page](http://landsat.usgs.gov//tools_project_documents.php), rather than the webpage documentation.

Alternatively, if you cannot find those details in a tech report, I would cite the webpage as a user manual with a URL.

Last, for your specific style questions are unanswerable without knowing your target venue (e.g, journal, report, thesis, etc.).

Comment: that's a great source ! thank you ! however, on my website, there are geometry information for Landsat TM, ETM, LE - which are splitted in tech reports. that's why I preffer to cite the whole website ...

Comment: The Tech reports have undergone a formal review and publication process. Personally, I would cite them because they are a more rigorous source.